# Spring TransactionInterceptor with Java 8 CompletableFuture

Tags: spring, java-8, spring-data, spring-transactions, completable-future

We use Spring `@Transactional` annotations on business layer methods. When we moved to Java 8 these methods have been converted to use Async features of Java 8 and use completable Futures and chain several async calls to the data layer. E.g.

```
@Transactional
public CompletableFuture<Entity> updateEntity(ID id) {
   repository1.get(id)
      .thenComposeAsync(item -> repository1.save(), executor); 
}
```

The above code demonstrates that we want to chain multiple database layer async calls.

The `@Transactional` annotation seems to only support blocking calls at this time and all the transaction context information is kept in `ThreadLocal`. The above method creates 3 transactions. The outer transaction starts and completes as soon as the future is returned. `repository1.get(id)` runs in another transaction and `repository1.save()` runs in it's own transaction.

Is there a standard way to have multiple async calls run in a single transaction without having to rewrite the transaction interceptor. Also seems like we need to copy thread local variables in `TransactionSynchronizationManager` from one thread to the other to get this to execute in a single transaction.
Appreciate feedback from Spring team if they have plans to enhance spring-tx to support this use case.

Comment: good question, but it is pretty known that spring transactional is bound to a single thread - I highly doubt that it could be possible to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar hurdle in a [problem I was trying to solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968086/single-transaction-across-multiple-threads-solution).

In short:

1. The easiest and most [effective way to solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709679/handling-transaction-in-multithreaded-environment) is via the producer-consumer pattern (and pipe to a single transactional worker thread). See example below.
2. If your problem is meniable to it, you could use [batching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784197/efficient-way-to-do-batch-inserts-with-jdbc)
3. You could solve this problem naturally with JTA, of which the transaction manager by definition deals with this problem (which, as you ask [spring-tx has supported since 2003](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html)), which would give you likely more overhead (and complexity) than you bargained for
4. Fiddle with the transaction interceptor and `TransactionSynchronizationManager` and solve via a hack-ey workaround which most TransactionManagers are not built to cope with

My transaction object in a single thread looked roughly like:

```
@Service
public class TransactionalObject {

    @Autowired
    private BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue;

    @Transactional
    public void consumeTransactionalRunnables() {
         try {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    Runnable execution = queue.take();
                    if (execution instanceof StopExecution) {
                        return;
                    }
                    execution.run();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }               
    }

}
```

This object was on its own thread, and the producer threads `put` onto the `BlockingQueue queue`. The [poison pill](https://dzone.com/articles/producers-and-consumers-part-3) in this code sample is the `StopExecution` Runnable type.

I found this solution to have minimal performance overhead (compared to other options), easily-manageable, easily-readable, and minimally invasive.

Comment: Does this mean all db calls in my application would execute on a single thread? If so, there would be a scalability issue, wouldn't it?

Comment: Regarding option 4, is there a TransactionManager implementation that works by passing lightweight context between threads (custom executor) for Spring?

Comment: If you were to go down this route, you would most likely have multiple transactional consumers (depending on how many transactions you want) for each transactional execution, and could easily create a factory of them. 
Even better, your idea to create a custom `Executor` would work great with `CompletableFuture`. You could use the Spring `TransactionTemplate` inside of your `execute`/`submit` method and instantiate it with the TM.